# How to get UniFi Captive Portal parameters to authenticate User Equipment with the UniFi API Client (ArtOfWiFi), when using CAPPORT API (RFC8908)?

Tags: dhcp, rfc, captiveportal, captivenetwork

I'm trying to get the 'new' CAPPORT API to work with the UniFi API Client by ArtOfWiFi. The UniFi API client is used to authenticate User Equipment (mobile phones, laptops, tablets), that go through the captive portal. The captive portal is just a simple ToS page with an accept button, no need for Radius or vouchers.

I can't figure out how to implement it. When the dhcp option 114 is configured (as described in RFC8910), the CAPPORT API gives a valid json response (as intended by RFC8908), and the User Equipment navigates to splashpage given by the CAPPORT API; I no longer receive the parameters I would normally get (stuff like: AP mac, Client mac, timestamp, SSID), when using the 'old' MITM-attack (http interception -> 302 redirect) method.

I can't identify or authenticate individual the User Equipment without passing these parameters to the UniFi API Client.

In my opinion have I tried nearly everything. From outputting every possible (global) variable to the console (and webpage), or debugging step by step in VSCode; to wiresharking and fiddling the connection between the User Equipment and accesspoint. I just can't seem to figure out how to get some form of information accross to identify the User Equipment.